# MS Access 2013 Report - Bad quality image on Print view, but fine on Layout view

Tags: vba, image-quality, ms-access-reports

In a **MS Access 2013 Report**, I import into an Image Control an image as OLE Object from an Oracle DB (from a BLOB column). The images are stored as .jpg to the DB with high resolution.

In Report View the image is correctly displayed, but in Print View the image is rendered really poorly:

[image]

I already tried to select the option "Convert all picture data to bitmaps" as suggested [here](http://accesscodetips.blogspot.ch/2008/10/settings-ms-access-2007-poor-image.html), but doing this not only does *not* solve the problem, but also triggeres the following exception on opening the report:

[image]

Why there is such a difference between Layout and Print View and how can I achieve the same quality also on Print View?

**EDIT**

If I select Size Mode = Clip for the Image Control, the image is displayed in a good quality, but of course only a fragment of it is visible.

[image]

Could it be that the original jpg image is too big in size and Access cannot "stretch" it correctly into the image control size (13x5cm)?

Comment: JPG (and all bitmaps) sucks for those jobs. The best format I could find (supported by Access) is definitely EMF. It's vectorial, so its scales perfectly. Great for logos. To create those I used Inkscape, which can read a PDF, select part of it, and save it as EMF.

Comment: Does the Print view really matter ? After all, it's rather a "preview" before printing. So the real question is: how does it look once printed, right ?

Comment: I tried as a test and the printed version looks good, therefore now I am waiting a feedback from the customer about it. Alternatively I proposed to reduce the image size (actually 1888x830px) to 20%, as that case the Print View is acceptable, but of course the final printed copy will not be in good quality.